# Mule Anypoint Studio slow to run a simple project

Tags: mule

What I can do to Anypoint Studio run projects faster? When I run a simple project I need to wait almost 20 seconds. My computer is a new macbook pro touch i7. When I run in a VM with Windows 10 the execution is very fast. It no make sense to me I tried many things like clear cache, increase the memory to Anypoint but nothing solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try maven project. On Run Configuration, try to add this to maven command **-DskipTests=true**

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that my Anypoint works slow (wait some seconds to run a project) when my computer is not connected in any network, when I connect my MAC in some network the Anypoint works fine. Don't make sense to me...

Answer (score 0):

The following steps will improve some performance. (for Windows)

- Add the directory of Any Point Studio in your Anti-virus exclusion list.
- Add C:\Users(username).m2\repository too in exclusion list.

Answer (score 0):

I  know that this is a very old question, but I anyway would like to put a perspective for new users.

Since we are talking about Anypoint Studio, firstly I would ask which version of the studio you are using.

> Is it mule 4 or mule 3 based ?!

`Mule 4 by default is embedded with maven unlike Mule 3, which is considered as Mule 4's little bother`.

If it's mule 4 you are using, you must for sure have to intialize and execute maven every single time you run the project. No way around it.

So if it takes 30 seconds then it must take 30 seconds. It has to load your configurations and modules ain't it !

Honestly, as a full time MuleSoft Developer, I have experienced way more wait time than 30 seconds for loading just few specific files using pom maven dependencies. Mostly 2 minutes on an Average. The wait time drastically increases exponentially when your machine memory is being used at its Max by other desktop applications.

---

But still nothing is lost yet. Follow the below steps and your day would be bright and cheerful.

```
1. Enable skip munits test while program build. 
    +Pass `mvn clean package -DskipTests` in Windows CMD.  
        (Note: This applies if you are building your APP target without studio)
    +Or pass `-DskipTests=true` in Maven Command Line Args in the studio run configurations.
2. Increase your java heap size through `AnypointStudio.ini` file.
     >  -Xms1024m
         -Xmx2048m
         -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
     +You can also add these in your run configurations with the `- D` tag before the above specified arguments. Try to understand what these arguments are used for !
```

**check this link** : [What are the -Xms and -Xmx parameters when starting JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvm)

```
3. Go to studio`s main exe directory > plugins > mule 4.x.x server (or 3.x.x server) > mule > logs. Here you will find all your application logs you recently ran individually. Clear your logs.
4. Always flush your %temp% directory before you start using the Studio.
5. Never use unnecessary maven dependencies. Remove the unused.
5. Finally close your workspace properly each time you shutdown.
```

**Hope this answer helps !**

Answer (score -1):

please check the RAm. Your computer RAM should be atleast 8 GB for anypoint studio to work.